Rule-Based Symbology associated with numerous fields at once
I hope that my picture explains my goal here in regards to rule-based symbology for the layer I'm creating.
I want to have rule-based symbology based off the functions listed in the image on the left, but when using this, it only returns null values. My workaround was using the method reflected on the right image, but this is obviously clunky and not how it can potentially be done, so it made me curious.

The idea is that we need to track polygon areas that have various treatments tied to various contractors, hence the "Treatment1", 2 and 3. The rule-based symbology helps show that any given polygon may have all three kinds of treatment, i.e. a polygon with a yellow fill, orange dashes and purple dots. I just want to streamline it so I have four fields instead of 10. And also to figure out why the function on the left isn't working for my own coding education.

I think your logic in the left hand image is wrong. it should read "Treatment1" = 'hand' or "Treatment2" = 'hand' etc. You may need to explicitly state for each field the value you need.

Oh my gosh that totally worked, and slightly embarrassing I didn't think of trying that. I feel slightly spoiled by the ArcPro function builder I was used to, so this was a good learning experience. Thank you!

The query for styling should include the field name and criteria for each instance.
So changing the current logic from:
"Treatment1" or "Treatment2" or "Treatment3" = 'hand'

to the correct:
"Treatment1" = 'hand' or "Treatment2"= 'hand' or "Treatment3" = 'hand'

will work.
